# Excel table to HTML and math - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

i need to write a code in JavaScript that reads and displays an excel table and after that calculates the situation of each student based on the average of the 3 tests (P1, P2 and P3), according to the table:

Average (m) Situation:

m<5 - Failed by Grade

5<=m<7 - Final Exam

m>=7 - Approved

If the number of absences exceeds 25% of the total number of classes, the student will have the status "Failed due to Absence", regardless of the average. If the situation is "Final Exam", it is necessary to calculate the "Final Approval Score" (naf) for each student according to the following formula:

5 <= (m + naf)/2

If the student's status is different from "Final Exam", fill in the "Grade for Final Approval" field with 0.

Round the result to the next whole number (increase) if necessary.

I managed to display the table but i have no idea how to calculate what it's asked

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ler e Calcular Tabela</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Carregue Sua Tabela</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><b>Selecione sua tabela do Excel</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

    if(!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type))
    {
        document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

        excel_file.value = '';

        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

    reader.onload = function(event){

        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

        var work_book = XLSX.read(data, {type:'array'});

        var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

        var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], {header:1});

        if(sheet_data.length > 0)
        {
            var table_output = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

            for(var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++)
            {

                table_output += '<tr>';

                for(var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++)
                {

                    if(row == 0)
                    {

                        table_output += '<th>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</th>';

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        table_output += '<td>'+sheet_data[row][cell]+'</td>';

                    }

                }

                table_output += '</tr>';

            }

            table_output += '</table>';

            document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
        }

        excel_file.value = '';

    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Well what exactly is the problem? Do you know how to calculate an average? You obviously would need to know the formula for that or google it if you have to. Same goes for percentages which you'll need. It's just basic maths.

Comment: as you are building the table, push the items into a 2d array.  then use some for loops on the respective columns/rows to calculate totals and averages.  it is also wise to know what each column means.